# Twitter.getHomeTimeLine() always return me only 20 status?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

For my Uni project a have to get some Twitter Statuses.
When i try to pull out twitter status using Twitter4j, i always get only 20 results.
What i do...

```
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
        User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
       // Paging paging = new Paging(200);     / i try with paging more than 20 but then result is 0;
        statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
```

is it some problem with lib and can  you advice me which lib to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the constructor with an `int` you are actually setting the `page` value and not adjusting the number of results to be returned. Instead you should do the following:

```
Paging paging = new Paging();
paging.setCount(200);

statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);
```

Refer to the documentation on [`Paging`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Paging.html) and [Twitter's documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline) for the API endpoint for more information.

By the way it's useful to know that not all API endpoints support all of the parameters that `Paging` offers. For example 'get home timeline' doesn't support the `page` parameter! Twitter4J has a guide on what parameters can be used with each API call [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/api-support.html).

Comment: using `twitter4j-streaming` is it possible to get a stream of user home timeline